# std::unique_ptr as parameter to function in std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, c++11, unique-ptr

So I'm trying to pass a `std::unique_ptr` as a parameter to a function that is launched in a separate thread, and I'm getting a strange error at compile time that reads:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1149): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Widget,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

A simplified version of this code, that still reproduces the same issue is:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Widget
{
public:
  Widget() : m_data(0)
  {
  }

  void prepareData(int i)
  {
    m_data = i;
  }

  int getData() const
  {
    return m_data;
  }

private:
  int m_data;
};

void processWidget(std::unique_ptr<Widget> widget)
{
  std::cout << widget->getData() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Widget> widget(new Widget());
  widget->prepareData(42);

  std::thread t(processWidget, std::move(widget));
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

My guess is that there is something wrong with the destruction of the `Widget` object from `main(`), however I cannot pinpoint the issue. Is it necessary to do something additional to cleanup that variable? By the way, I'm using VS2013.

Comment: @DevSolar doesn't `std::thread` always pass an xvalue to its handler, and this is an MSVC malfunction?

Comment: GCC accepts it. `std::thread t([&widget]() { processWidget(std::move(widget));});` Also works.

Comment: works well in Orwel DevC++ 5.11 bro !! nothing seems wrong with your code

Comment: now i have got a problem !! why am i not able to send widget by `reference` !!! the compiler displays error !!!

Comment: IIRC this is a known issue in MSVC. At least I remember searching for it here and one of the comments in my code is "using shared_ptr with bind because VS chokes on unique_ptr here" and it seems likely creating a thread goes via bind as well

Comment: Wow. And they call it a compiler?

Comment: @SergeyA please suggest us a compiler free of bugs then

Comment: @stijn there all different sort of bugs. This one is a plain showstopper.

Answer (score -1):

You are not allowed to make copy of unique_ptr, therefore the copy constructor is disabled. That is pointing the compiler error.

You can fix it with a reference:

```
void processWidget(std::unique_ptr<Widget>& widget)
```

Comment: noone is making a copy in the OP's code

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Not directly but the constructor for [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) copies/moves its arguments to thread acessible storage and then that is copied when calling the function itself.

Comment: @sjdowling can you please provide a standard reference which says that `std::thread` makes a copy to call its handler?

Comment: this doesn't work, check my comments
plus the `move` statement is correct & works in Orwell DevC++
the problem is with VS2013 & not the code