# why can't I send object by reference using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference

My code goes like this :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
void swapno (int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
int main()
{
    int x=5, y=7;
    cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << "\n";
    thread t (swapno, x, y);
    t.join();
    cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This code fails to compile. Can anyone help me out why ?
Not only this code but the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870414/stdunique-ptr-as-parameter-to-function-in-stdthread/33871495#33871495) also failed to send `std::unique_ptr` by reference. What's wrong with `std::thread` ?

Comment: You may be explicit with reference by using `std::ref` (i.e `thread t (swapno, std::ref(x), std::ref(y));`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `std::thread` *copies* its arguments and stores them internally. If you want to pass an argument by reference you need to use the [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) or [`std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/cref) functions to create reference wrappers.

Like

```
thread t (swapno, std::ref(x), std::ref(y));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, instead:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    void swapno (int *a, int *b)
    {
        int temp=*a;
        *a=*b;
        *b=temp;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int x = 5, y = 7;
        std::cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << "\n";
        std::thread t (swapno, &x, &y);
        t.join();
        std::cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

You should achieve the same result ;)