# using std::move in std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, move

I encountered yet another problem with `std::thread` & this time while applying `std::move` to swap 2 values. My code says :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
void swapno (int &&a, int &&b)
{
    int temp=move(a);
    a=move(b);
    b=move(temp);
}
int main()
{
    int x=5, y=7;
    cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << "\n";
//  swapno (move(x), move(y));  // this works fine
    thread t (swapno, move(x), move(y));
    t.join();
    cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
x = 5   y = 7
x = 5   y = 7
```

Now what's wrong in this method ? Why is such the code showing such a behaviour ? How do I correct it ?

Comment: The thread use a copy of `x` and `y` not a ref to them. You can pass the pointer to `x` and `y` instead.

Comment: The reasons are the same as for your previous question. Also, use `std::swap`.

Comment: how did you go from "[you have to wrap it in an std::ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33895159)" to using &&?

Comment: trying both at a time @Default :P

Comment: swapping of temporairies works @WernerErasmus, try the `swapno` function without a thread

Comment: After `std::move(x)` the variable `x` can't be use as rvalue since is value was move to another variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `thread` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) you're calling

> copies/moves all arguments (both the function object f and all
>   args...) to thread-accessible storage as if by the function:

```
template <class T>
typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v) {
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

And [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) will remove cv-qualifiers, which includes r-value references.

Thus, when `std::thread` is copy/moving arguments to thread-accessible storage, it's essentially move constructing **it's own** `int`s from the ones you provided, and because a `move` on an `int` is simply a copy, when you perform `swapno` on its values, you're doing it on copies.

To correct it, use `std::ref` plus `swap`:

```
std::thread t ([](int& a, int& b){std::swap(a, b);}, std::ref(x), std::ref(y));
t.join();
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f7d5e559f39d2a6)

Comment: so according to you we can't use `rvalue references` with `threads` ?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: Not exactly. You shouldn't use rvalue references when you want to access the data afterwards. In your case, `std::move` on an int is useless, but if you wanted to perhaps give the thread it's own `vector<T>` to work on (which you constructed in the main thread), then `std::move`'ing that `vector` is useful.

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms, thread's constructor accepts temporaries/rvalues to the arguments passed to the function. Therefore you have to wrap it with a reference_wrapper, which is a value but wraps the underlying reference (what std::ref does).

The code below does the trick with std::swap out of the box. Using std::swap as argument to thread (or std::function) causes and ambiguous overload (which surprised me too).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int x = 5, y = 7;
  std::cout << "x(" << x << ")" << " y(" << y <<")" << std::endl;
  void (*pf)(int& x, int& y) = std::swap<int>;
  std::thread t1(pf, std::ref<int>(x), std::ref<int>(y));
  t1.join();
  std::cout << "x(" << x << ")" << " y(" << y <<")" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```